# Resteasy @FormParam null when passing params with AngularJS

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, resteasy

I'm trying to use AngularJS in front end and Resteasy as  a Rest API.
My problem is that my @FormParam are always null when sending params with AngularsJS.

Here is how my JS :

```
$scope.addPerson = function(newFirstName, newLastName) {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: "rest/persons/savePerson",
                data: {firstName: 'newFirstName', lastName: 'newLastName'},
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            })
            .success(function(data) {
                alert("DATA  : " + data);
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("Could not save new person");
            });
        };
```

And this is my code server side :

```
@POST
@Path("/savePerson")
@Produces("application/json")
@Secured({ "ROLE_USER" })
public PersonBean savePerson(@FormParam("firstName") String firstName,
        @FormParam("lastName") String lastName) {
    if (firstName== null || lastName== null) {
        return null;
    }
    PersonBean person = personDao.savePerson(firstName,
            lastName);
    return person ;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are posting the fields as JSON, not as form encoded data.

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

But you can't just change this header. The values will need to be Form encoded. See this page on how to post form data from Angular.

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2615-posting-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs.htm

Although, you may find it better to stick with JSON and let your framework map these fields to a Bean for you.

I haven't used Resteasy but I think it should be as simple as...

```
@POST
@Path("/savePerson")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
@Secured({ "ROLE_USER" })
public PersonBean savePerson(SavePersonBean savePersonBean) {
    PersonBean person = personDao.savePerson(savePersonBean.getFirstName(),
            savePersonBean.getLastName());
    return person;
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, he also have to add '@Consumes("application/json")' to the method